# Nginx Redirect of HTTP to HTTPS partially working

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https

My objective is to redirect my web site like this:

http://EXAMPLE.com/ to https://EXAMPLE.com/ (working)

http://www.EXAMPLE.com/ to https://EXAMPLE.com/ (not working). This one is currently redirecting to https://www.EXAMPLE.com/.

In addition, even though I didn't define api.EXAMPLE.com in the server section below, when I enter the URL as http://api.EXAMPLE.com/, it gets redirected to https://api.EXAMPLE.com/. I believe this has to do with the DNS record resolving to the same IP address. I would rather it show page not found instead of redirecting.

DNS Records:

> ```
> Type  Name    Value           TTL 
> A     @       35.161.XX.XX    600 seconds
> A     api     35.161.XX.XX    1 Hour
> A     www     35.161.XX.XX    1 Hour
> ```

And the Nginx configuration file:

> ```
> # For more information on configuration, see:
> #   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
> #   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/
>
> user nginx;
> worker_processes auto;
> error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
> pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
>
> # Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
> include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
>
> events {
>     worker_connections 1024;
> }
>
> http {
>     log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
>                       '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
>                       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
>
>     access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
>
>     sendfile            on;
>     tcp_nopush          on;
>     tcp_nodelay         on;
>     #keepalive_timeout  65;
>     keepalive_timeout   15;
>
>     types_hash_max_size 2048;
>
>     # Enable HTTPS by default on all our websites
>     #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
>
>     #php max upload limit cannot be larger than this       
>     client_max_body_size 40m;
>
>     include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
>     default_type        application/octet-stream;
>
>     # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
>     # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
>     # for more information.
>     include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
>
>     index   index.php index.html index.htm;
>
>     # Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for PHP.
>     upstream php {
>         #this should match value of "listen" directive in php-fpm pool
>         server unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
>         #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
>     }
>
>     # Redirect unsecured port 80 traffic (http://) to port 443 (https://)
>     server {
>         listen       80 default_server;
>         listen       [::]:80 default_server;
>         server_name  EXAMPLE.com www.EXAMPLE.com;
>   #return 301 $scheme://EXAMPLE.com$request_uri;
>         #return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
>   return 301 https://EXAMPLE.com$request_uri;
>     }
>
>     #server {
>     #    listen       80 default_server;
>     #    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
>         #server_name  localhost;
>     #    server_name  EXAMPLE.com;
>         #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
>     #    root         /var/www/nginx;
>
>         # Load configuration files for the default server block.
>     #    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
>
>         # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
>         #
>         #location ~ \.php$ {
>         #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
>         #}
>
>     #}
>
>     # Settings for a TLS enabled server.
>     server {
>         listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
>         listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
>         server_name  EXAMPLE.com;
>         root         /var/www/nginx;
>
>   #For Basic Auth
>   auth_basic "Restricted";                                
>   auth_basic_user_file /var/www/nginx/.htpasswd;
>
>         #ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/tls/certs/EXAMPLE.crt";
>         #ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/tls/private/EXAMPLE.key";
>         ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.com/cert.pem";
>         ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.com/privkey.pem";
>
>         # It is *strongly* recommended to generate unique DH parameters
>         # Generate them with: openssl dhparam -out /etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem 2048
>         #ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";
>         ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/tls/dhparams.pem";
>         ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
>         ssl_session_timeout  10m;
>         ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
>         ssl_ciphers HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP;
>         ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
>
>         # Load configuration files for the default server block.
>         include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: It behaves like [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) is in effect. If you have recently disabled HSTS, you will need to reset your browser to make it forget.

Comment: Thank you Richard. Based on your lead, I was able to reset my HSTS in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the lead from Richard, here is how I erased the HTTP [Strict Transport Security history from Chrome](http://chrome://net-internals/#hsts):

1. In the Query Domain section, I entered my domain and sub-domains: example.com, www.example.com, db.example.com, api.example.com to see if they were listed.
2. Then I entered those I found into the Delete Domain section and pressed Delete.
3. I entered http://www.example.com into the browswer's location field and pressed Enter. It redirected to https://example.com.
4. I also tried http://db.example.com and http://api.example.com and both were redirected to https://example.com. **I'm curious why these got redirected since I didn't have a server section for them in nginx.conf.** Is it because it resolved to the same IP?
5. Lastly, I tried http://what.example.com and got a "Can't reach this page" error; which is right.

chrome://net-internals/#hsts